# How to use value of one class to another class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two classes, `Calculate` and `CircularProg`.  In my `Calculate` class, there is a variable called `sum`. I want to use this variable value(int) as the value of `CircularProgressIndicator` which is in `CircularProg` Class. I am doing like below image. But it doesn't work.
How can I do it?

In my Calculate class, I am doing this code:

```
class Calculate extends StatefulWidget {
 const Calculate({Key key}) : super(key: key);
 @override
  _CalculateState createState() => _CalculateState();
}
class Sum {
  static int babi ;
  static int chld ;
  static int  sum ;

}

class _CalculateState extends State<Calculate> {
  final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("pets");
  List lists = [];
  int babi =0;
  int chld=0 ;
  int  sum =0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Flutter Circular Progress Bar"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
      ),
      body:  Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: dbRef.onValue,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print("Error on the way");

            }
            else if(!snapshot.hasData){
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            else  {
              DataSnapshot dataValues = snapshot.data.snapshot;
              Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = dataValues.value;
              lists.clear();
              values.forEach((key, values) {
                lists.add(values);
              });

              return new ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: lists.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,  index) {
                  String age = lists[index]["age"];
                  int baby = lists[index]["baby"];
                  int child = lists[index]["child"];

                  void onAddButtonPressed() {

                    int value = int.parse(age);

                    sum += value ;
                    babi += baby;
                    chld += child;
                    print('sum: $sum');
                    print('babi: $babi');
                    print('chld: $chld');
                  }
                  return InkWell(

                    onTap:(){
                      onAddButtonPressed();
                      },
```

In my CircularProg class, I want to use that varibale(sum) value. I was trying this way. But it said, method "/" was calling on null. How should I solve this problem?

```
class CircularProg extends StatelessWidget {


  int totalValue= 1200;
  //int sum;
   Sum sum;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
........
child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          value:  (Sum.sum /100)*totalValue,
          valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),

        ),
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you made sum a static variable on a class, that is a super dirty way to do it and probably what you should not be doing, but in order to make it work, remove these lines: `int babi =0;`, `int chld=0 ;`, `int  sum =0;`, and change this: `Sum.sum += value ;  Sum.babi += baby;  Sum.chld += child;  print('sum: ${Sum.sum}');  print('babi: ${Sum.babi}');  print('chld: ${Sum.chld}');`

Comment: I have changed my code: ``` 
                  void onAddButtonPressed() {

                    int value = int.parse(age);

                    Sum.sum += value ;
                    Sum.babi += baby;
                    Sum.chld += child;
                    print('sum: ${Sum.sum}');
                    print('sum: ${Sum.babi}');
                    print('sum: ${Sum.chld};
                  }``` and in CircularProg class I wrote like this: ```value:  (Sum.sum)/100*totalValue,```--- but it said, The method '/' was called on null.

Comment: That's weird, are you using an old version of flutter? Could you give the sum variables a default value? Like this: `class Sum {
  static int babi = 0;
  static int chld = 0;
  static int  sum = 0;
}` and see if that works?